Is it worth exporting SFMC engagement data if connected to Data Cloud with Starter Bundle Data Streams?
With SFMC's upcoming 180-day data retention policy (effective Jan 15, 2025), I'm considering whether exporting engagement data to external storage (e.g., S3) is necessary.
I already have a connection between SFMC and Data Cloud, using Starter Bundle Data Streams, which automatically send all engagement data to Data Cloud daily.

Does Data Cloud store these engagement data streams indefinitely, or is there a retention limit?
Are there scenarios where additional external storage (like S3) would still be valuable for long-term archiving or external integrations if we use Data Cloud with a starter bundle of data streams from SFMC?

